# Struggling to add numbers in a list together (unsupported operand type)

Tags: python, list

Trying to get this program to work for a school project, but in line 26 of the code I get an unsupported operand type error for 'int' and 'str'. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
final = False
while final == False:

    while True:
            try:
                eventName = str(input("What is the event's name? "))
                numberJudges = int(input("How many judges are there? "))
                competitorName = str(input("What is the competitor's name? "))
                judgeScores = input("Please enter the judges scores with a space between each one. ")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a valid name or number(s)") 
    finalJudges = numberJudges - 2

    def judgeScoreListFunction(judgeScores):
        judgeScoreList = judgeScores.split()
        return judgeScoreList

    def cleanJudgeScoresFunction(judgeScoreList):
        judgeScoreList.remove(max(judgeScoreList))
        judgeScoreList.remove(min(judgeScoreList))
        finalJudgeScores = judgeScoreList 
        return finalJudgeScores

    def cleanScoreFunction(finalJudgeScores, finalJudges):
        cleanedScore = sum(finalJudgeScores)
        finalScore = cleanedScore / finalJudges
        format(finalScore, '.2f')
        return finalScore

    judgeScoreList = judgeScoreListFunction(judgeScores)
    finalJudgeScores = cleanJudgeScoresFunction(judgeScoreList)
    finalScore = cleanScoreFunction(finalJudgeScores, finalJudges)

    if competitorName == "Finish":
        final = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
judgeScoreList = judgeScores.split()
```

You want:

```
judgeScoreList = [int(X) for X in judgeScores.split()]
```

I'd also recommend getting rid of all these little single-purpose functions.

Comment: Oh thanks so much, I'd like to get rid of the functions but the task says to show that you can use functions, so I figured this was the easiest way. Anyway thanks!